# Adding React Component child to another React Component at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am super stuck with ReactJs in trying to add one Virtual Component to another Component at runtime and failing to do so. Here is what I am trying to do:

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

// Components
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import LeftSideSpace from './components/LeftSideSpace';
import RightSideSpace from './components/RightSideSpace';
import CenterSpace from './components/CenterSpace';

// main class name: App
class App extends React.Component {
  // main function name: render
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header title='My Blog'/>
        <LeftSideSpace/>
        <CenterSpace/>
        <RightSideSpace/>
        <Footer title='Welcome! This is my Blog site'/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My focus is on the component `<CenterSpace/>` which I am importing from here:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class CenterSpace extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <centerspace className="Site.CenterSpace">
                <div id="Site.CenterSpace.Content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </centerspace>
        );
    }
}

// props defaults
CenterSpace.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Personal Blogger\'s site'
}

// props validations
CenterSpace.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default CenterSpace
```

Then I have a menu component like this, as of now, this is what I have in code, which I am sure contains bugs:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import CenterSpace from '../CenterSpace'
import HomeLists from './HomeLists'

class MainMenu extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Site.MainMenu">
                <button onClick={this.props.onClickHome}>Home</button>
                <button onClick={this.props.onClickBlogs}>Blogs</button>
                <button onClick={this.props.onClickAboutMe}>About Me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// props defaults
MainMenu.defaultProps = {
    //control button clicks
    onClickHome: () => {

        var home_dom = new HomeLists();
        var center_dom = new CenterSpace<String>("My Blog list");

        console.log("say we went to home")
         center_dom.appendChild(home_dom);
    },
    onClickBlogs:() => {
        console.log("say we went to blogs")
    },
    onClickAboutMe:() => {
        console.log("say we went to about me")
    }
}

// props validations
MainMenu.propTypes = {
    onClickHome: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onClickBlogs: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onClickAboutMe: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default MainMenu
```

This main-menu is used to dynamically add and remove components, but I am failing to do so. When I click `Home` button, the action I am trying achieveis to add `<HomeList/>` component to `<CenterSpace/>`. And futher, `<HomeList/>` is parsing some Json files and appending as child `div`s.

`<HomeList/>` looks like this (may have some issues, was not able to make it work, but that is something I can fix):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class HomeLists extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const fs_obj = require('fs');
        const fs_path = require('path');

        const fs_jsons = fs_obj.readdirSync('../data').filter(file => fs_path.extname(file) === '.json');
        fs_jsons.forEach(file => {
            const file_data = fs_obj.readFileSync(fs_path.join('../data', file));
            const json = JSON.parse(file_data.toString());

            const blog_title = json.title;
            var snippet_header = document.createElement('h3');
            snippet_header.textContent(blog_title);

            const blog_desp = json.blog.content[0].value;
            var snippet_text = document.createElement('p');
            snippet_text.textContent(blog_desp);

            var snippet = document.createElement('div');
            snippet.appendChild(snippet_header);
            snippet.appendChild(snippet_text);

            this.appendChild(snippet);
        });

        return (
            <homelists className="Site.HomeLists">
                <div id="Site.HomeLists.Content">{HomeLists}</div>
            </homelists>
        );
    }
}

// props defaults
HomeLists.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Personal Blogger\'s site'
}

// props validations
HomeLists.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default HomeLists
```

Right now when I click Home, all I get is the following error:

```
TypeError: center_dom.appendChild is not a function
onClickHome
src/components/complications/MainMenu.js:29
  28 |     console.log("say we went to home")
> 29 |     center_dom.appendChild(home_dom);
     |    ^  
  30 | },
  31 | onClickBlogs:() => {
  32 | 

console.log("say we went to blogs")
```

Can anyone help me get unblock from here.

Comment: I think you should provide a codesandbox replication link for easy access to see the running code. It can be a stripped down version, but would be helpful. One of the first doubts is I have with the code is, what exactly are you trying to do with this line of code ? `var home_dom = new HomeLists();` HomeLists is a component and you must declaratively use it like `<HomeLists />`, as opposed to what you are trying to do

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai sorry, I am new to Frontend development. I am not aware of any code sharing sandbox. What I am trying to do is adding an element as an action to button click. I do not how can `<HomeLists />` be used to add a child.

Comment: Why don't you think of using conditional rendering to render the relevant components with button clicks if necessary.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I am just getting started with ReactJs and haven't come across of conditional rendering yet. I am will be checking it out now. In case you have a example link, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following component as an example for conditional rendering and it is based on your question as well.

```
import React from "react";

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isHome: false, isBlogs: false, isAboutMe: false };

    // Binding this keyword
    this.onClickHome = this.onClickHome.bind(this);
    this.onClickBlogs = this.onClickBlogs.bind(this);
    this.onClickAboutMe = this.onClickAboutMe.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHome() {
    this.setState({ isHome: true, isBlogs: false, isAboutMe: false });
  }
  onClickBlogs() {
    this.setState({ isHome: false, isBlogs: true, isAboutMe: false });
  }
  onClickAboutMe() {
    this.setState({ isHome: false, isBlogs: false, isAboutMe: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Site.MainMenu">
        <button onClick={this.onClickHome}>Home</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClickBlogs}>Blogs</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClickAboutMe}>About Me</button>

        {this.state.isHome && <div>Home view is enabled</div>}
        {this.state.isBlogs && <div>Blogs view is enabled</div>}
        {this.state.isAboutMe && <div>AboutMe view is enabled</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

**Application View**

[image]

Refer this link for more info on conditional rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html